# Issue with Sum Calculation for multiple different IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

The SQL code I have is shown below. The issue I am having is with calculating the sum of the Value of each Number. Doing them separately is okay and works when the Number is specified in the code but not when the number is not specified and I want the sum calculation to work for all separate Numbers.

{ Looks to calculate the value at the point of Tax. So all values before the tax date are ignored and all unit entries that occurred after the tax date are subtracted off the total units. The tax units are also subtracted off. The total units at point of tax, for each fund, is multiplied by the price at point of tax. The values of the funds are summed giving a total value for the number. }

This is the code I have done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

A.Number,

CAST(ROUND((SELECT SUM(Val)
FROM (SELECT((S.TotalUnits -  
 (SELECT SUM(Units) 
FROM TableIH AS F WHERE F.Fund = S.Fund AND F.Number = S.Number 
AND F.Date >= (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM TableIH AS D 
            WHERE D.Fund= F.Fund AND D.Number = F.Number AND D.Entry = 'Tax'     )
  )
        ) * T.Price
  ) AS Val

FROM TableIH T
 INNER JOIN TableID S
 ON T.Number = S.Number

 WHERE S.TotalUnits > 0 AND T.Fund = S.Fund
         AND T.Price = ANY (SELECT (Price) 
    FROM TableIH AS E WHERE E.Entry = 'Tax' AND E.Number = T.Number)
   )t
   )
  ,2) 
 AS DECIMAL (25,2)) AS "Value"


 FROM
TableIH A
INNER JOIN TableID C
ON C.Number = A.Number 


 group by A.Number
```

Tables are:

TableIH:

Number    Fund    Entry    Units     Price           Date

12           YY       RE           6          0.2          2015-02-02

12           YY       Tax          -10         0.1          2015-01-13

13           XX       RE           6         0.2           2015-02-12

13           XX       Tax          -20         0.05         2014-12-11

13           MM       Tax          -25         0.6          2014-12-10

13           MM       RE           8           0.2          2013-11-02

TableID

Number      Fund     TotalUnits

12             YY          2000

13             XX          1500

13             MM          500

DESIRED RESULT:

Number                  Value

12             [ ((2000) - (6) - (-10)) * 0.1 ] = 200.4

13             [ ((1500) - (6) - (-20)) * 0.05 ] + [ ((500) - (-25)) * 0.6 ]  = 390.7

BUT GETTING: - Result is summing all instead of dividing it between each number.

Number                  Value

12             [ (200.4 + 390.7] = 591.1

13             [ (200.4 + 390.7] = 591.1

Any help with the errors would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening, The problem is in your third nested subquery, you have no group on your sum, so it's summing all units, so you'll only get one total:

```
SELECT SUM(Units) 
FROM TableIH AS F WHERE F.Fund = S.Fund AND F.Number = S.Number 
AND F.Date >= (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM TableIH AS D 
        WHERE D.Fund= F.Fund AND D.Number = F.Number AND D.Entry = 'Tax'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help :)
I have included a line that should ensure the units are summed for each  number only

However, this give back an error of "subquery returns more than 1 row"
My results and calculations need to be returning results for multiple numbers. Any tips on how to fix this? 
                                                                                    
      `(SELECT SUM(Units) 
 FROM TableIH AS F 
      WHERE F.Fund = S.Fund AND F.Number = S.Number
      AND F.Units = (SELECT DISTINCT Units 
  FROM TableIH AS E where E.Number = F.Number)
 AND F.Date >=  ...` 


Thanks